# How to return memory address of directory graph to use later checking the item?

Tags: javascript, emscripten, webassembly

I want to use dawg in my javascript project. I converted dawg code [here](http://code.google.com/p/dawgdic/) to webassembly using Emscripten.

This project provides a library dawgdic for building and accessing dictionaries implemented with directed acyclic word graphs (DAWG).

A dawg is constructed by minimizing a trie as a deterministic finite automaton (DFA), and thus the dawg has an advantage in memory usage

I took reference of given link for conversion into Webassemly. [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/C_to_wasm)

```
The below code store items in dawg graph format.
    #include <cassert>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <dawgdic/dawg-builder.h>
    #include <dawgdic/dictionary-builder.h>
    #include <emscripten/emscripten.h>
    using namespace std;

    #ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C" {
    #endif
    int EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE addToDawg(void(*f)(dawgdic::Dawg *c)) {
         dawgdic::DawgBuilder dawg_builder;
  assert(dawg_builder.Insert("apple"));
  assert(dawg_builder.Insert("cherry"));
  assert(!dawg_builder.Insert("banana"));
  assert(dawg_builder.Insert("durian"));
  dawgdic::Dawg dawg;
  dawg_builder.Finish(&dawg);
        return 0;
      }

    #ifdef __cplusplus
    }
    #endif

    Here is link to see output: [here](https://demophp.digi-corp.com/nitin/dawg-builder-test.html)

    How can I return address of memory segment where dawg is stored to Javascript such that later I can call another method to check if item exist in dawg graph? like dawg_dic.Contains("apple").
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to create a `dawgdic::Dawg` on the heap (using new) and then return its address.   On the JS side this returned value will simply be number and then you can pass this to a function that takes a `dawgdic::Dawq*`.

So your API might look like:

```
dawgdic::Dawg* createDawg() EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE;
void addToDawg(dawgdic::Dawg *c) EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE;
```

Comment: Now I am storing reference of dawg graph in Vector and returning index of that to Javascript. Here is code link : (https://demophp.digi-corp.com/nitin/dawg-builder-test.cpp). When I call main function from javascript then I am getting correct value in return but if I first call  addToDawg method and then try to call findInDawg..It is not returning me correct value.   Here is demo page link: (https://demophp.digi-corp.com/nitin/dawg-builder-test.html)